# Decoding / reverse engineering math content

Tags: functional-analysis

I came across the following image while browsing internet:

[image]

Is this some kind of coded message? Or it has some real math meaning? Or it is just a joke?

My math knowledge is way below the level needed to understand symbols and equations above, that's why I am asking you for help.

Feel free to retag the question.

Comment: I think [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) are relevant.

Comment: Image probably from https://www.drupal.org/node/330215.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Poisson Summation Formula (in particular the distributional version)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula#Distributional_formulation

Also, on notation above: $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ are the Fourier transform, and inverse Fourier transform, respectively.  $G[n]$ is presumably the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of $G$.  And $g$ and $G$ presumably are a Fourier transform pair, that is, $G = \mathcal{F}(g)$.  I will assume you can look up the Fourier transform if you don't know it already.